# Windows prompt content variable as variable name

Tags: windows, prompt

It is possible in windows command line refer to a content variable like a pointer?

Example:

```
SET envTEST=FOO    
SET envPROD=BAR    

SET CURR=envTEST
SET data=%%CURR%%
```

I want to data contains **FOO** but it contains **%envTEST%**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need multiple rounds of expansion. See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053) for an explanation as to why the following work:

**From the command line:**

```
call set "data=%%CURR%%"
```

Or if delayed expansion has been enabled by `cmd /v:on`, then:

```
set "data=!%CURR%!"
```

**From within a batch script:**

```
call set "data=%%%CURR%%%
```

or

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
...
set "data=!%CUR%!
```

If CURR is set and expanded within the same code block (typically done within IF or FOR loop), then:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
...
(
  set "CURR=envTEST"
  for %%V in (!CURR!) do set "data=!%%V!"
)
```

The CALL technique is quite slow, so I try to avoid it. It is not an issue for a single use, but it can become a major problem (slow performance) if used within a tight loop.